# Using cx_freeze to create executable of Python code with additional text files

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I'm using Python 3.6 and cx_freeze to create an executable for a Python game I've created. The game is a random sentence generator that uses three text files for its dictionaries.

e.g. "names.txt":

```
 def random_name():
    line_num = 0
    selected_line = ''
    with open('names.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = f.readline()
            if not line: break
            line_num += 1
            if random.uniform(0, line_num) < 1:
                selected_line = line
    return selected_line.strip()
```

When I try to create the build and then run the exe I get the following error:

```
cx_Freeze: Python error in main script
Traceback (most recent call last):
File
"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 14, in run module.run()
File
"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 26, in run exec(code, m.__dict__)
File "rcg.py", line 55, in <module>
File "rcg.py", line 22, in random_name
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'names.txt'
```

The reason why I mention that the code uses separate txt files is that I think this might be the reason for the error, although I do not understand all of the error message.

If this is correct, how do I make sure that cx_freeze includes these extra files?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not freeze, it is the file 'names.txt' location. Are you sure the names.txt are in the same location as the .py file? I did copied your code sample and ran it. It gave me the same error. SO I created a file names.txt and it 'worked'

Updated Answer:
My setup.py was as follows:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"]}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "Random Crime Generator",
        version = "1.0",
        description = "A random crime generator for police states",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("rcg.py", base=base)])
```

And rcg.py was as follows:

```
import random

def random_name():
    line_num = 0
    selected_line = ''
    with open('names.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = f.readline()
            if not line: break
            line_num += 1
            if random.uniform(0, line_num) < 1:
                selected_line = line
    return selected_line.strip()
```

For the names.txt, which was in the same folder as rcg.py I only added the following:

```
Apple
Banana
Carrots
```

That is all and it run fine. I was running t from Windows.

Comment: They are in the same location. What did you put in the names.txt file? Did you add anything to the setup.py? Here is my setup.py code.

import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name = "Random Crime Generator",
    version = "1.0",
    description = "A random crime generator for police states.",
    executables = [Executable("rcg.py", base = "Win32GUI")])

Do I need to add anything to this?